# Calculating Yearly Percentage from multiple values from a Single column and in a Single SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor, percentage, calculation

Have been looking for some help regarding "Calculating Percentages from values present in a Single Column in a Single SQL table".

Please, allow me give you a little heads-up (as below):

1.) I am working in my test Environment which is on SQL2008 and Need to deploy code which is on SQL2012.

2.) I am using an SQL Cursor because I need row-by-row processing of results and

3.) These results I am putting into a new table using the query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_1 (Column_names) 
SELECT @Column_names_from_cursor_variables
```

---

4.) There are (as of now) exactly 3 records per id as:

```
present_year_value (say,MAY2017), 
last_quarter_value (say,MAR2017)
last_year_value (say,MAY2016)
```

as follows:

```
id     yearValue   salesQty  
-----------------------------
1       052017        9876    
1       032017        5432    
1       052016        1000    
---------------------------    
2       052017        9876    
2       032017        5432    
2       052016        1000    
---------------------------    
3       052017        9876    
3       032017        5432    
3       052016        1000    
---------------------------
```

and So on...

I need to calculate the Percentage_YoY (Year-On-Year) as well as 
Percentage_QoQ (Quarter-On-Quarter) for each block of id as:

```
QoQ --> ((present_year_value-last_quarter_value)/last_quarter_value)*100

YoY --> ((present_year_value-last_year_value)/last_year_value)*100
```

But, somehow I am not able to get the trick in the SQL Cursor. (Using SQL Cursor is NOT mandatory but I needed row-by-row computation of results hence I preferred the Cursor).

Comment: What is id here in this table? (like product id or any unique id related to another table?)

Comment: Hello Samanvitha, The Id is Primary key in the table and it has (exactly) 3 records each

Comment: What is the problem? What is the result you are getting that is not correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a longer answer than you want, but I want to address several important things about your table setup and why they matter. My explanation will be a little bit backwards, but hopefully it will be easy to follow.

The example data you give can be a little bit confusing because it is all the same for each id, so I'm going to change them a bit to look like this:

```
Data
+ -- + --------- + -------- + 
| Id | YearValue | SalesQty | 
+ -- + --------- + -------- + 
| 1  | 052017    | 9876     |
| 1  | 032017    | 5432     |  
| 1  | 052016    | 1000     | 
| 2  | 052017    | 6483     |
| 2  | 032017    | 2211     |
| 2  | 052016    | 580      |
| 3  | 052017    | 11316    |
| 3  | 032017    | 1216     |
| 3  | 052016    | 9487     |
+ -- + --------- + -------- +
```

To start, the answer would be immediately obvious if your table looked like this instead:

```
Values
+ -- + ----------- + ---------------- + ---------------- + ------------- +
| Id | CurrentDate | PresentYearValue | LastQuarterValue | LastYearValue |
+ -- + ----------- + ---------------- + ---------------- + ------------- +
| 1  | 052017      | 9876             | 5432             | 1000          |
| 2  | 052017      | 6483             | 2211             | 580           |
| 3  | 052017      | 11316            | 1216             | 9487          |
+ -- + ----------- + ---------------- + ---------------- + ------------- +
```

Then, assuming your datatype for the SalesQty field is not a decimal, you could use the following query:

```
select    Id
        , cast((PresentYearValue - LastQuarterValue) as float) / (LastQuarterValue) * 100 as QoQ
        , cast((PresentYearValue - LastYearValue) as float) / (LastYearValue)  * 100 as YoY
    from Values
```

and you get the following results:

```
Results
+ -- + ------ + ------- + 
| Id | QoQ    | YoY     |
+ -- + ------ + ------- +
| 1  | 81.81  | 887.6   |
| 2  | 193.22 | 1017.76 |
| 3  | 830.59 | 19.28   |
+ -- + ------ + ------- +
```

Very simple and straightforward.

**BUT...**

It may not always be feasible to make changes like this in your database. For example, the data is probably used for more than just this single problem and storing it in your format might be the best overall. In that case, here is a walkthrough of how to transform the data to get the results you want.

To make our Data table look like our Values table, we need an explicit *ordering* within the Id's. In this case, we can order on the YearValue field *but only* if they are actual dates, not strings. Consider the following query:

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Id order by YearValue desc) as RN
    from Values
```

This gives us a table similar to Data but with a new field:

```
Data
+ -- + --------- + -------- + -- +
| Id | YearValue | SalesQty | RN |
+ -- + --------- + -------- + -- + 
| 1  | 052017    | 9876     | 1  | -- PresentYearValue
| 1  | 032017    | 5432     | 2  | -- LastQuarterValue
| 1  | 052016    | 1000     | 3  | -- LastYearValue
| 2  | 052017    | 6483     | 1  | -- repeat
| 2  | 032017    | 2211     | 2  |
| 2  | 052016    | 580      | 3  |
| 3  | 052017    | 11316    | 1  |
| 3  | 032017    | 1216     | 2  |
| 3  | 052016    | 9487     | 3  |
+ -- + --------- + -------- + -- +
```

Notice the correspondence between RN and (Present,Last)(Quarter,Year)Value. We can exploit this correspondence to "pivot" the rows into columns.

```
select    a.Id
        , case RN when 1 then a.YearValue end as CurrentDate
        , case RN when 1 then a.SalesQty end as PresentYearValue
        , case RN when 2 then a.SalesQty end as LastQuarterValue
        , case RN when 3 then a.SalesQty end as LastYearValue
        , a.RN as RN
    from (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by SalesQty desc) as RN
            from #Values
    ) a
```

which gives us a table like

```
+ -- + ----------- + ---------------- + ---------------- + ------------- + -- +
| Id | CurrentDate | PresentYearValue | LastQuarterValue | LastYearValue | RN |
+ -- + ----------- + ---------------- + ---------------- + ------------- + -- +
| 1  | 2017-05-01  | 9876             | NULL             | NULL          | 1  |
| 1  | 2017-05-01  | NULL             | 5432             | NULL          | 2  |
| 1  | 2017-05-01  | NULL             | NULL             | 1000          | 3  |
| 2  | 2017-05-01  | 6483             | NULL             | NULL          | 1  |
| 2  | 2017-05-01  | NULL             | 2211             | NULL          | 2  |
| 2  | 2017-05-01  | NULL             | NULL             | 580           | 3  |
| 3  | 2017-05-01  | 11316            | NULL             | NULL          | 1  |
| 3  | 2017-05-01  | NULL             | 9487             | NULL          | 2  |
| 3  | 2017-05-01  | NULL             | NULL             | 1216          | 3  |
+ -- + ----------- + ---------------- + ---------------- + ------------- + -- +
```

With a quick grouping we can collapse this table.

```
select    a.Id
        , max(case RN when 1 then a.YearValue end) as CurrentDate
        , max(case RN when 1 then a.SalesQty end) as PresentYearValue
        , max(case RN when 2 then a.SalesQty end) as LastQuarterValue
        , max(case RN when 3 then a.SalesQty end) as LastYearValue
    from (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by YearValue desc) as RN
            from Data
    ) a
    group by a.Id
```

and this gives us exactly the values table:

```
Values
+ -- + ----------- + ---------------- + ---------------- + ------------- +
| Id | CurrentDate | PresentYearValue | LastQuarterValue | LastYearValue |
+ -- + ----------- + ---------------- + ---------------- + ------------- +
| 1  | 052017      | 9876             | 5432             | 1000          |
| 2  | 052017      | 6483             | 2211             | 580           |
| 3  | 052017      | 11316            | 1216             | 9487          |
+ -- + ----------- + ---------------- + ---------------- + ------------- +
```

Lastly, tuck the last query into a CTE and combine it with the first query to get the values you want:

```
; with
    Values as (
        select    a.Id
                , max(case RN when 1 then a.YearValue end) as CurrentDate
                , max(case RN when 1 then a.SalesQty end) as PresentYearValue
                , max(case RN when 2 then a.SalesQty end) as LastQuarterValue
                , max(case RN when 3 then a.SalesQty end) as LastYearValue
            from (
                select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by YearValue desc) as RN
                    from Data
            ) a
            group by a.Id
    )
select    Id
        , cast((PresentYearValue - LastQuarterValue) as float) / (LastQuarterValue) * 100 as QoQ
        , cast((PresentYearValue - LastYearValue) as float) / (LastYearValue)  * 100 as YoY
    from Values
```

Add any additional fields you want and your *into* clause before the from clause. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ohh Gosh @KindaTechy, I have read this Tutorial kind-of reply but by the look of things, I think this can work (I still have to try this entire thing out though). Please give me sometime to reflect on this code and try out with a few minor changes. Will surely get back to you on this. Once again, Thank you! in advance  and #allCreditToYou_KindaTechy

Comment: @E.Hunt I hope this works for you. Let me know if it doesn't, and maybe we can figure out why :)

Comment: Yes it works and I was able to modify it with the help from your logic and a Big thank you for guiding me. Learnt alot from this hardwork of yours.

Comment: @E.Hunt, glad to hear it. Feel free to mark this as the answer.